# how to check the value of an NaN error

Tags: javascript, foreach, indexof

Hi so my logs.date prints out the actual date of the log, but when i push it
 into a new array called dates, it gives me Nan at every index of that array. This is my first time using a forEach loop and indexOf function. Do any of you guys see whats wrong with it??

Here's my code:

```
theLogs.forEach(function(logs){
                //if this line gets you 0 or higher it found it at that index, if you get -1 it was not found.
                var index = dates.indexOf (logs.date);
                if (index > -1){
                    //it was found so increment
                    dates[index]++;
                }
                else {
                    //it was not found so add a new entry in dates
                    dates.push(logs.date);

                    counters[counter] = 1;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you show us how you instantiate the `dates` variable?

Comment: chris walsh i just go like his    var dates = [];

Comment: amanuel, logs are just a couple of statements that i have. they contain a couple of things including a date.

Comment: `var dates = [];` looks fine but it would be helpful to include it in the code sample and anything else that could affect the code (such as your logs object)

Comment: you are right about that. im not sure i can change it know though. But do you know whats going on?

Comment: to be more specific there is an array of logs called theLogs. it contains a number of logs in it. each log is an object with a date time and message. so im trying to retrieve a logs date and only its date, then push it into a new array called dates.

Answer (score 0):

If `logs.date` is `undefined` then incrementing it will give you a `NaN` value.

```
> undefined++
< NaN
```